# How can I define a key mapping in vim and use the repeat number more than once?

Tags: vim, mapping

I edit files with relative line numbers. Often I would like to copy a line from let's say 16 lines above to the current location.

In normal mode I would enter: `16kyy16jP`

But when it is line 14, it is: `14kyy14jP`

How can I define a key mapping/command to be able to enter something like `16LK` or `14LK` in normal mode to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 5):

> `16kyy16jP`

What a waste… You could use `:help :t` instead:

```
:-16t.
:-14t.
```

Comment: I thought about the :t too, but he wants to Paste above the . line. we have to do a `-16t-1` or  `-ddp` after the `t` command.

Comment: "16 lines above to" and `jP` make me think that's not the case.

Comment: But even then: `:-16t+`.

Comment: Actually when you say `t.` which means copy to current line the content is placed one line below, hence if you want to past on the current line you should do `:-16t-1`. Also have a look at your selection mode if it is blockwise or linewise, because this affects your paste

Answer (score 3):

May be something like

```
nnoremap <silent> µ :<c-u>exe "normal! ".v:count1."kyy".v:count1."jP"<cr>
```

But, honestly, I'd use functions here as there is no need to move around that much:

```
nnoremap <silent> µ :<c-u>call append(line('.')-1, getline(line('.')-v:count1))<cr>
```

Note that the following also works thanks to `:yank`

```
nnoremap <silent> µ :<c-u>exe '-'.v:count1.'y'<cr>P
```

EDIT: I didn't know about `:t`, @romainl's answer (with @Kent's patch) makes more sense than mine. If you want a mapping it could be mode with:

```
nnoremap <silent> µ :<c-u>exe '-'.v:count1.'t-1'<cr>
" which isn't much different than the previous answer.
```

Comment: I like (and tested) this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can map a function call, which accepts input parameters.

```
function! YourMap(n) 
    exec 'normal! '.a:n.'-Y'.a:n.'+P'
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>c :call YourMap(input('lines:')) <CR>
```

You press `<leader>c`, then input the relative line numbers, the copy/paste should be done.

The `<leader>c` is the mapping key, you can change it into other key combinations.